# SEO - wrong sitemap links

Tags: seo, sitemap

My domain have about 40000 links and my sitemap was wrong generated. It was poiting to localhost instead public domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        <url>
            <loc>http://localhost/phpCupom/cp-web/sitemap/home.xml</loc>
            <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        </url>
        <url>
            <loc>http://localhost/phpCupom/cp-web/sitemap/coupon.xml</loc>
            <changefreq>weekly</changefreq></url>
        <url>
            <loc>http://localhost/phpCupom/cp-web/sitemap/store.xml</loc>
            <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        </url>
    </urlset>
```

What could be the consequences of this wrong sitemap? The GWT show most of my 40000 urls indexed, but show a alert mark in the sitemap.

Comment: Are you sure sitemap.xml ahs no seo value? I also encountered it in my SEMrush audit. I installed xml sitemap plugin and deleted the sitemap.xml in my ftp.

Comment: Sitemaps don't have SEO value as they don't directly affect rankings. But they do serve other purposes and should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sitemap doesn't determine what gets index and what does not, Google and other search engines will still crawl links found on the actual pages in fact Google prefers this method and it'll use the sitemap to confirm what its already discovered and ensure that no pages have been missed, which a sitemap can help if your site is insanely big or a website that is Ajax powered or similar that Google and other search engines may have a hard time crawling.

The fact that you have 40,000 urls indexed is evidence that your site is being crawled with no problems and a sitemap won't help SEO in anyway.